# A name followed by parenthesis and braces

Tags: javascript

In [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), there is this code fragment:

```
const ShapeB = {
    a() {
        console.log('aaa');
    }
};
```

What does the construct `a() { ... }` mean? Doesn't `a()` usually mean the invocation of the function `a`?

Comment: short for `a: function()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
};

console.log(obj.foo());
```

It is a shorthand method to assign a function to its name. They are mainly used as setter and getter function which is introduced in ES5
visit to know in details [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)